# What is the Apollo Choke?

Tags: training, technique, brazilian-jiu-jitsu, chokes

Following [this](https://www.facebook.com/10thPlanetJiuJitsuMelbourne/videos/876223035802778/) video, I would like to know what is the Apollo Choke? When is it recommended to use this choke? Are there any detailed instructions how to do it? Why is it called the Apollo Choke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Apollo choke" is the 10th Planet term for an arm triangle from bottom half guard:<sup>[1](https://www.ultimatejujitsu.com/forum/695/apollo-choke/) [2](https://www.10thplanetjj.com/threads/20753-Apollo-choke)</sup>

> **Apollo Choke**
> The Apollo choke is an arm triangle done when holding a lockdown half guard.
>
> - https://jiujitsulegacy.com/bjj-lifestyle/10th-planet-jiu-jitsu-terminology/

There are many instructional videos on this position e.g:

- [Lockdown 101 - Apollo Series - Jaws of Life to Apollo Control](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=p7JM1CedBg8)
- [Arm Triangle Choke from Bottom Half Guard | MMA Submissions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Byl_lvMQYA0)

As for why it is called this:

> The main reason that Bravo began using different Jiu Jitsu terminology was for coaching purposes. Only he and his student know the instructions he’s given during a fight or match.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it called the Apollo?
https://www.10thplanetjj.com/techniques/mts-170-samurai-calf-slicer/

1 hour in

Comment: Reiterating the comment left by mattm on your other answer: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible."

Comment: Please add context to this answer to prevent it being deleted as a link-only answer.